# Setup multi-functional connection Android-Ubuntu via USB

Tags: networking, usb, android, tablet

I'm currently facing a connectivity challenge and would greatly appreciate your expertise in resolving it. Here's the situation:

I own an Android tablet and a Jetson Orin NX device running Ubuntu. My goal is to connect the tablet to the Jetson Orin NX via a USB/USB-C cable and achieve the following functionalities **simultaneously** and **automatically** without any additional manipulation by the user:

**Charge Tablet from Device** (Default Behavior): I'd like the tablet to draw power from the Jetson Orin NX, which is the default behavior when connected via USB.

**Access to Internet Connection from Device**: It would be fantastic if I could share the Jetson Orin NX's internet connection with my tablet. This could prove useful for various applications and services on the tablet.

**Access to Device File System from Tablet**: Simultaneously, I'm looking to access the file system of the Jetson Orin NX directly from my tablet.

I need advice on how to achieve this multifunctional setup. If you've successfully configured a similar connection or have insights into the necessary configurations on the Android tablet and Jetson Orin NX, please share your knowledge.

Any information, tutorials, or suggestions on the steps involved, required software/tools, and potential challenges would be immensely helpful. I'm eager to learn from your experiences and make this connectivity setup a reality.

Thanks a ton in advance for your assistance!